# Dismiss UIViewController does not deallocate memory

Tags: ios, memory, modalviewcontroller

I have this code

```
 -(void)didPressButton:(int)tag
    {
        // Preventivi?
        if (tag == 0)
        {
            if (addPrev == nil)
                addPrev = [[avvAddPreventivoViewController alloc] init];
            addPrev.delegate = self;
            UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addPrev];
            navigationController.navigationBarHidden     = NO;
            [[navigationController navigationBar] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
            [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
            addPrev = nil;

        }
    }
```

When I show up the `addPrev` the memory increases, when show off the memory does not release.
When the `addPrev` dismiss it fires a protocol methos, `didCancel`. I intercept it and release `addPrev`:

```
  -(void)didCancel
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
         addPrev = nil;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This means some other object has a reference to the view controller. You need to use Instruments to determine what that reference is.

Comment: addPrev is called only once as in the code I wrote...

Comment: Are you sure you are using ARC? The graph that you have shown is typical of what would show up with your code if you have turned off ARC.

Comment: YEs it is turned on, in fact I can't use "release" at all...

Comment: gosh i have the same issue , how did u solve it ?\

Answer (score 1):

Niling also the navigation controller improves drastically the memory allocation.
Also, be careful to deallocate what you can deallocate in the dealloc of the pushed controller.

```
-(void)didPressButton:(int)tag
    {
        // Preventivi?
        if (tag == 0)
        {
            if (addPrev == nil)
                addPrev = [[avvAddPreventivoViewController alloc] init];
            addPrev.delegate = self;
            UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addPrev];
            navigationController.navigationBarHidden     = NO;
            [[navigationController navigationBar] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
            [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
            addPrev = nil;
            navigationController = nil;

        }
    }
```